# What statistics can I use to combine multiple rankings in order to create a final ranking?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, ranking

I have a list of genes and I am checking certain factors for each gene. I have individual scoring system for each factor for each gene. My final table/matrix looks like this:

```
Gene    Factor1    Factor2    Factor3    Factor4
ALS     0.006      1.0        2.3        0.8
NCLS    0.09       0.8        1.8        0.18
MLB     0.4        0.0        1.8        0.78
BJ      1.1        0.0        0.75       0.18
```

The scores for each factor are independent and comparable to scores within that factor only, i.e., 1.1 is very good for `factor1`, but may not be so good for `factor3`. However, for any given factor, the higher the number the better.

What I am trying to achieve is a ranking of genes. From the example, ALS and MLB should be on the top because for ALS, factors 2-4 have highest values, for MLB, `factor2` is 0 but other factors have high values.

Can you suggest what statistics can be used on matrices like this to create a ranking and level of significance? Can I normalize the scores for each factor by calculating Standard Score/z-score (even though all of them don't follow a normal distribution)? What other normalization can be done? Can I instead rank the genes independently for each factor, and then somehow combine the ranks to create a final ranking?

Answer (score 7):

Let $r_{g,i}$ be the rank of gene $g$ in ranking $i$ (out of a total of $k$ rankings). Then a statistic which pools these ranks together is the [rank product statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_product), which is just the geometric mean of the ranks:

$$RP(g) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^k r_{g,i}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}$$

The rank product statistic was mainly developed to pool together independent replicates, but I think it should work nicely for your use case as well, since you claim that the different scores are independent.

There also exists a R [package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RankProd.html), which implements this statistic (as well as calculates significance/p-values), though I have never used it.

Comment: How would I deal with negative rank values? or rank values that are zero?